# Numpy function, adding the log of the exponential. Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, exponential

I am new user to Python.

I want to add many exponential functions, and then take (and store in memory) the logarithm of the result. (Side note : I am doing this because the sum of the exponential functions is very large so storing the log value of this result is a workaround). Can anyone help me use this numpy function https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html

In the below code I have a 2 x 2 matrix M and a 2 dimensional vector v. I want to first add v the columns of M. So in the below code the result should be

```
[[11, 22], [13, 24]]
```

Then I want to take the exponential of each value and sum across the rows (ending up with a vector of length 2), and storing the logarithm of the result. However the below code outputs a matrix and I cant work out how to use the "out=None" imput for the logaddexp function.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
v = np.array([10, 20])
result = np.logaddexp(M, v[None, :])
```

Comment: `np.logadexp()` calculates log(exp(x1) + exp(x2)) but in your description you add first and then exponentiate... so which is it? The latter would be `np.log(np.exp(M + v).sum(axis=1))`

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
v = np.array([10, 20])

result = np.logaddexp.reduce(M + v, axis=___)
```

Fill in ___ depending on what "sum across the rows" means

---

Consider the difference between [`np.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) and [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html).

- `np.add`, much like the + operator, *always* takes in 2 arguments, x1 and x2, and adds them together. `np.add` is a numpy [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html). If x1 or x2 is an array_like, then the arguments are [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) together.
- `np.sum` *always* takes in 1 argument, typically an array_like of items, and performs a summation of all of the elements in the array_like. This is essentially equivalent to iteratively taking an element from the array_like and repeatedly calling `np.add` with that element on a running result variable. The running result variable is initialized with 0.

Similarly, what `np.sum` is to `np.add`, `np.prod` is to `np.multiply` (with running result initalized as 1).

Every `np.ufunc` (such as `np.add` and `np.multiply`, but also `np.logaddexp`), comes with a [`reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) method and an accompanying [`identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.identity.html) property that is used as initialization for the running result.

`np.add.reduce` is exactly equivalent to `np.sum`. `np.multiply.reduce` is exactly equivalent to `np.prod`.

What you're looking to do is a `log-sum-exp`; but numpy only offers `np.logaddexp`. As such, you can use `np.logaddexp.reduce` to get the required functionality. Confusion arises from the fact that you're adding `M` and `v` as well as adding exponential terms together. You can simply perform the `M + v` operation first, and pass the resulting array (the intermediate result in your question), to `np.logaddexp.reduce`. Note that `M + v` is equivalent to `M + v[None, :]` in this case due to numpy's broadcasting rules.

Comment: shouldn't you use `dtype=np.float64`? Like this: `np.logaddexp.reduce(M + v, axis=1, dtype=np.float64)`. For integer arrays I get a TypeError. Thanks for suggesting `.reduce` solution :)

Answer (score -1):

The function `np.logaddexp()` performs an elementwise operation. In your case, you need the addition to be performed along a given axis. Using some basic functions, you can try the following.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])  # '2 x 2' array
v = np.array([[10, 20]])        # '1 x 2' array
sum_Mv = M + v                  # '2 x 2' array
result = np.log(np.sum(np.exp(sum_Mv), axis=1))
```

Change the 'axis' parameter if needed.

If you still want to use `np.logaddexp()`, you can split the summed matrix into two halves and perform the operation as shown below.

```
result = np.logaddexp(sum_Mv[:, 0], sum_Mv[:, 1])
```